# How do I specify the EntityManager used by Symfony2 Form->handleRequest?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, entitymanager

I have multiple EntityManagers for my Symfony2 app. I've set a default and then have a few others listed. This configuration works and is functional in my code with the exception of Forms.

When trying to handle the request, the `handleRequest(mixed $request = null)` presents an error as the Entity type that I'm trying to verify the form against does not exist in the default manager, but inside of another.

Is there a way to specify which Entity Manager is used in handling the request?

```
$form = $this->createForm(
    new UserType(), $user
);

$form->handleRequest($request); // $request is coming from form submission
```

The error I get is clear:

```
An exception occurred while executing [select statement appears here]

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'DEFAULTENTITY.User' doesn't exist
```

It is true that the User table doesn't exist on the default entity so this error is not unexpected. I want to be able to specify that the handleRequest function check against the `dev` EntityManager, where the User table does exist.
The function in its entirety is below. This function works perfectly when utilizing only the default EntityManager, but breaks down when I implemented a multiple-manager environment:

```
public function addAction(Request $request)
{
    $user = new User();

    $form = $this->createForm(new UserType(), $user);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    // Respond to a form submission
    if ( $form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager( $this->currentManagerID );
            $em->persist($user);
            $em->flush();
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('user_add'));
    }

    // Render the form
    return $this->render(
            'MyBundle:User:create.html.twig',
            array('form' => $form->createView())
    );
}
```

My multiple-entity Doctrine configuration works in all other aspects of the application. I am able to utilize the default manager to load up application-wide settings and use the subdomain to choose an EntityManager for which to check against for Login, Selections, institution-specific settings, etc.

```
orm:
    default_entity_manager: default
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
    entity_managers:
        default:
            connection: default
            mappings:
                MyBundle: ~
        dev:
            connection: dev
            mappings:
                MyBundle: ~
```

Comment: Have you done `$ php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force`?

Comment: I have; to be clear (which being my first time posting here I might not have been), the usage of multiple EntityProviders works across the various aspects of the application -- login, selections (for tables, etc), grabbing data, etc.

The issue I've run into is when I utilize the Form Builder: the built-in functionality of handleRequest is checking against Doctrine's default EntityManager.  What would be wonderful is if there was a `handleRequest($request, $em)` option.  Since there's not, I was hoping for a way to specify which manager I would like to use.

Comment: Right, sorry I cannot help you more, I've never used more than one EntityManager in my `SF` apps.

Comment: are you absolutely sure the handleRequest() is causing this? maybe its a persist to the db?

Comment: I am -- I captured the "breaking point" by use of a die().  Placement directly before the handleRequest() functions, directly afterwards throws the exception before the die() is processed.

Comment: Can you show us your function ? You can define your entity manager with : $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('nameOfEntityManager');

Comment: @PerroinThibault I've included the entire function -- you'll notice that where I'm trying to specify which Manager to use happens before the typical block of code that is used for EntityManager options.

Comment: Ok thx, and what is your doctrine config in config.yml ?

Comment: @PerroinThibault I've included the Doctrine orm configuration. The configuration works well with all other aspects of the application. I believe that the issue I'm running into exists due to the handleRequest function relying only on the default manager.

Comment: I think you have to specify which entity of your bundle in your orm mappings bundle. Like : MyBundle: { type: annotation, dir: Entity/DEV, prefix: My\Bundle\Entity\DEV}

Comment: The mappings are done automatically and seem to work correctly. Proof of this is that the form is generated corrected by using the Entity. The problem is that each EntityManager (with the exception of the default) will reference the same Entity types so I can't hardcode an Entity to a specific manager.

Comment: The first step is to define your form types as services then inject the appropriate entity manager or repository.  Then go here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#using-a-custom-query-for-the-entities and define custom queries.  In some cases you can also use the em property, http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#em, and just name the entity manager but I like the injection approach better.

Comment: @Cerad, Thank you for your help with service injection. To allow multiple entities throughout the application, I've had to inject the entity manager into custom-defined services. I will take a look into those documents going forward. I posted a solution below that identified the problem, but will research further into Custom Queries as you posted to see if the Constraint issue can be better solved through those means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that `handleRequest` is the function that goes through and parses your Entity annotations and ensures that the Constraints are not violated. In my User table, I identified a UniqueEntity constraint that checked on the username field inside of `My\Bundle\Entity\User.php`.

`@UniqueEntity(fields="username", message="Username already taken")`

Specifically, it was this Constraint that was referencing the default EntityManager, not the call of `handleRequest`. Removing this constraint allowed the request to be handled and the form to be persisted.

As such, I am marking this question as answered. I will do more thorough research to see if I can specify which EntityManager is used when checking constraints and create a new thread in the event I am still stuck.

Comment: The UniqueEntity has an em property which you can set to the name of your entity manager.  You can also make your own constraints as services and inject your repositories.

Answer (score 1):

I am having the exact same issue. It seems that the handleRequest method uses the first available entity manager that has mappings for the entity being persisted which is not necessarily the correct one. I would also like to know how to specify another entity manager.

Are there any new solutions or updates?

Comment: Dre, what fixed it for me was how I specified the constraints in the Entity itself. Utilizing the default "unique" constraint resulted in handleRequest checking against the default EM. I defined my own as a service from which I was able to pull the desired manager from the session. When I get back I'll post more detailed information.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick reply. I'm not using the "UniqueEntity" validator at the moment. However, after a full day of debugging, I finally realized that my problem was in a custom listener that I programmed some time ago and completely forgot about. If anybody else is interested, you can simply pass the name of the entity manager to the entity field type using the 'em' option. In my case, I have a dynamic form so I was using a PRE_SUBMIT listener and recreating the same field within the listener. I simply had to add the 'em' option to the recreated field in the listener and everything worked